# Recursive function not returning despite stop condition being met

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a contains function on my Tree class to check if the tree contains a value or not. Although my stop condition is being met (verified by a console log), the function does not return true.

```js
class Tree {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild (tree) {
    this.children.push(tree);
    return true;
  }

  contains (value) {
    if (this.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.children.length === 0) return false;
    for (let tree of this.children) {
      tree.contains(value);
    }
  }
}


const tree = new Tree('hello');
const subTree = new Tree('world');
console.log(tree.addChild(subTree) === true);
console.log(tree.contains('world') === true);
```

Comment: have you tried with `return tree.contains(value);` ?

Comment: When you enter the loop, you don't  `return` anything.

Comment: try walking the code with a debugger. that can be a valuable resource

Comment: @keja that logic would fail to check anything after the first child.

Comment: ah yea was too fast :D, but there is missing some return somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the first `true` find from the children and at the end return `false` as default value.

```js
class Tree {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild (tree) {
    this.children.push(tree);
    return true;
  }

  contains (value) {
    if (this.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.children.length === 0) return false;
    for (let tree of this.children) {
      if (tree.contains(value)) {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

const tree = new Tree('hello');
const subTree = new Tree('world');
console.log(tree.addChild(subTree) === true);
console.log(tree.contains('world') === true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value inside the loop. Instead of just calling the `tree.contains` function, you need to check if the function returns true and return true if it does and return false after the for loop is complete.

```js
class Tree {
      constructor (value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
      }
    
      addChild (tree) {
        this.children.push(tree);
        return true;
      }
    
      contains (value) {
        if (this.value === value) {
          console.log('foobar') //logs 'foobar' when tests are run
          return true;
        }
        if (this.children.length === 0) return false;
        for (let tree of this.children) {
          if(tree.contains(value)){
           return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
var tree = new Tree('oak');
console.log(tree.contains('oak'));
var tree2 = new Tree('birch');
tree.addChild(tree2);
var tree3 = new Tree('pine');
tree.addChild(tree3);
console.log(tree.contains('birch')&&tree.contains('pine'));
```

Comment: This is incorrect and will fail to search children after the first child.

Comment: you return with the first children.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this recursive function only works on its first call, in the unlikely scenario when the tree's root contains the value. However, if a child of the root has the value, the results of that finding aren't passed up the call stack. Here's a code example:

```js
class Tree {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild (tree) {
    this.children.push(tree);
    return true;
  }

  contains (value) {
    
    // if this node has the value, tell its parent
    if (this.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    
    // this node doesn't have the value, but if any
    // of its children do, report that to the parent
    for (let tree of this.children) {
      if (tree.contains(value)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // neither this node nor any of its descendents have
    // the value; the search is exhausted on this tree
    return false;
  }
}

const tree = new Tree("a");
const subTree = new Tree("b")
tree.addChild(subTree);
tree.addChild(new Tree("c"));
subTree.addChild(new Tree("d"));

console.log(tree.contains("a"));
console.log(tree.contains("b"));
console.log(tree.contains("c"));
console.log(tree.contains("d"));
console.log(tree.contains("e"));
```

The example tree looks like this:

```
      a
    /   \ 
   b     c
  /
 d
```

Let's walk through a search for node `d`:

```
a: a doesn't have d, enters the loop and asks b if it has d
    b: b doesn't have d, enters the loop and asks d if it has d
        d: d has d and immediately reports to b that it does
    b: b immediately reports to a that it has d
a: a immediately reports to the global scope that it has d
```

Let's walk through a search for node `e`:

```
a: a doesn't have e, enters the loop and asks b if it has e
    b: b doesn't have e, enters the loop and asks d if it has e
        d: d doesn't have e and has no children to search and returns false to b
    b: b's loop is exhausted and reports false to a
a: a has another child, c, and asks it if it has d
    c: c doesn't have e and has no children to search and returns false to a
a: a's loop is exhausted and reports false to the global scope
```

Incidentally, you can see that this tree's search time is linear time complexity, in contrast to balanced [binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), which have *O(log n)* search time complexity. BSTs might not be able to organize the same kind of data you may be using this tree to store, though, so I only mention it in passing.